# How to connect Loopback app to google database with ssl enabled?

Tags: loopbackjs, google-cloud-sql

I'm attempting to connect a Loopback app to a Google SQL database, and I've altered the Datasource.json file to match the credentials. However, when I make a GET request in the Loopback API explorer I get an error. I have not found any docs on how to specify the ssl credentials in Datasource.json and I think this is causing the error.

I've fruitlessly attempted to change Datasource.json and below is the current state. I've changed details for privacy, but I'm 100% certain the credentials are correct as I can make a successful connection with javascript.

```
{
  "nameOfModel": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "host": "xx.xxx.x.xxx",
    "port": xxxx,
    "user": "user",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "sql_db",
    "ssl": true,
    "ca" : "/server-ca.pem",
    "cert" : "/client-cert.pem",
    "key" : "/client-key.pem"
  }
}
```

This is the error the command line returns when I attempt a GET request on the loopback API explorer. The "Error:

> Timeout in connecting after 5000 ms" leads me to believe it's not reading the ssl credentials.

```
Unhandled error in GET /edd-sales?filter[offset]=0&filter[limit]=0&filter[skip]=0: 500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at EddDbDataSource.DataSource.queueInvocation.DataSource.ready (D:\WebstormProjects\EDD-Database\edd-api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:2577:81)

(node:10176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Timeout in connecting after 5000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\WebstormProjects\EDD-Database\edd-api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:2572:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)

(node:10176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:10176) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure datasource.json allows you to specify "ssl" connections? Where did you get that information? I have checked their [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/datasources.json.html#database-connector-properties) and they don't show the "ssl" properties that you are using. Neither it specifies so on the MySQL connector [properties](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/MySQL-connector.html#properties).

You have two options:

1.- Create the connection without using SSL.

2.- Create your own [connector](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) or use an existing one with ssl options implemented. Have in mind that this might causes issues with LoopBack framework.

Don't matter which of the two options you decide to use, remember to **Whitelist** your IP (the IP from where you are trying to access the database instance), you can do so on the Cloud Console, on the "Connections" tab, under "public IP" Authorized networks. If you don't do this it can cause the timeout error that you are getting.

Comment: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/347 There is a comment "datasource can accept options "ssl": true, but make sure don't use url parameter." This is the reason I think it's possible. I have all IPs whitelisted using (0.0.0.0/0) on my Cloud Console.

Comment: If you have whitelisted the IP (0.0.0.0/0 is valid but not recommended) then you shouldn't be facing the timeout error, since loopback will just ignore the "ssl" unvalid properties and will try to establish a normal connection (I have confirmed this myself), and I'm assuming you have not configure your instance with "SSL connections only" because you are not getting "permission denied" error. Please check your source code and verify that all the configuration data is valid, follow this tutorial if you aren't sure ->  https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Getting-started-with-LoopBack.html

Comment: Be aware that my previous comment was referring to the fact that you are facing a timeout error, to confirm that you are able to connect to the database (not through ssl).

Comment: My google Cloud SQL instance has been SSL connections only. I can get it to work by removing the ssl config but that's what I'm trying to avoid. As I've mentioned in the question, I CAN connect to my database with a simple js script with SSL or without (if I allow non unsecured connections on my SQL instance) so I'm 100% sure that I can connect. The roadblock has been the Loopback ssl config.

Comment: I can confirm that if I disable SSL then the loopback application works with my instance with the same credentials. Also, the docs tutorial you shared is outdated as it's for Loopback2 and I'm working with Loopback4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I wanted to be sure that the issue didn't rely on Cloud SQL. I'm afraid I know nothing about LoopBack framework so I can't be of much help with that, I was going to advise you to contact them but I see that you have already created an issue on their github.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am using `lookback3` and it works well for me. You need to create `datasources.local.js` in order to properly load `CA` files.

#### datasources.local.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  nameOfModel: {
    name: 'db',
    connector: 'mysql',
    host: 'xx.xxx.x.xxx',
    port: 'xxxx',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'sql_db',
    ssl: {
      ca: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/server-ca.pem`),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/client-cert.pem`),
      key: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/client-key.pem`),
    },
  }
}
```

Notice that instead of using `ssl: true`, you need to use an object with those properties.